# Set fill color of excel chart based on labels (xvalues)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a couple of pie charts in Excel 2010 based on data that looks like the one below (labels on the left column, values on the right) and I wanted to make sure that the fill color of each segment of the pie charts, corresponding to the labels, gets painted a specific color. Two caveats:

(1) It's a lot of graphs so I hope to automate this procedure via VBA or something similar.

(2) Only a subset of all labels appears in each graph, so simply using the set color palette won't work.

(For instance, if I had labels A, B, C and D and they all showed in every chart, I could set up the Excel color palette in a way that followed this order. In my data, however, we might get a graph with only A, B and D, and another with B and C - in this case, Excel would color B in the second graph like A in the first one, by default, which is NOT I want).

The first solution to this I could think was to set up a Subroutine that looks something like this (only pseudocode below):

```
For each worksheet in workbook.sheets
    For each chart in worksheet.charts
        Get list of xvalues(labels)
        Map labels to fill colors(this mapping could be in an Excel matrix)
        Change fill colors based on list of fill colors generated above
```

Any ideas on how best to implement this?

[image: data example]

Comment: Are your charts embedded in the worksheet or separate charts sheets?

Comment: The charts are in same worksheet as the data. I'm currently using pivot charts, but I could switch to regular charts if that makes any difference.

Comment: I image you've tried `Page Layout -> Themes -> Colors` but it does not do what you want? If so why, exactly?

Comment: You might want to read and implement the following: https://peltiertech.com/vba-conditional-formatting-of-charts-by-series-name/

Comment: Nice, thanks for the link!

Comment: The more applicable link on my blog would be [VBA Conditional Formatting of Charts by Category Label](https://peltiertech.com/vba-conditional-formatting-of-charts-by-category-label/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could help.

```
Sub FormatPieChart()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cht As Chart, srs As Series, p As Integer

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "ColorMap" Then

            For i = 1 To ws.ChartObjects.Count

                Set cht = ws.ChartObjects(i).Chart

                If cht.ChartType = xlPie Then

                    Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(1)

                    For p = 1 To srs.Points.Count
                        srs.Points(p).Format.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent & MapColor(srs.XValues(p))
                    Next p

                End If

            Next i

        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

Function MapColor(xval As Variant) As Integer
    MapColor = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(xval, Worksheets("ColorMap").Range("A1:B5"), 2, False)
End Function
```

**NOTES**

1. On a separate sheet `ColorMap` I have a list of labels and color values (A1:B5)
2. As far as I can tell the fill color is set using `msoThemeColorAccent`.
3. There are only so many permissible values. You can see the [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.msothemecolorindex?view=office-pia)
   here. The color values set in column B *must* match one of the
   valid `msoThemeColorAccent` values.

Comment: Looks good! Just checking: you're getting the color mappings based on the reference code for the currently selected color palette (the mso Theme Colors) and not on their RGB or hex codes, correct?

Comment: You get to define the colours in **ColorMap** worksheet. The caveat is that the colour code must be one from the link I included (I.e. the Microsoft enumerations)